# Partial update using ajax jquery and wcf odata service

Tags: wcf, odata, put

I am trying to update a single value of a record in the database using PUT request from java script to my WCF oData service. The code for the calling the service is

```
var upda = { stat: $("#com_status_txt").val() };
                upda = JSON.stringify(upda);
                console.log(upda);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "PUT",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "http://localhost:65401/sdrservice.svc/issues('" + sessionStorage.currentIssue + "')/stat",
                    data: upda,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        //Some code goes here...
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {                            
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(xhr));

                    }
                });
```

where **sessionStorage.currentIssue** is my id for the issue and i need to update the **stat** field in table.

But when I run this service I receive following error.

```
  {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"\",\"message\":
{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"An error occurred while processing this 
request.\"},\"innererror\":{\"message\":\"A top-level property with name 'stat' 
was found in the payload; however, property and collection payloads must always 
have a top-level property with name value' . 
\",\"type\":\"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException\",\"stacktrace\":\"   at 
Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer.
<>c__DisplayClassc.ReadTopLevelPropertyImplementation>b__5(PropertyParsingResult propertyParsingResult, String propertyName)\\r\\n   at 
Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightDeserializer.ProcessProperty(Duplic
atePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Func`2 
readPropertyAnnotationValue, Action`2 handleProperty)\\r\\n   at 
Microsoft.Data.OData.JsonLight.ODataJsonLightPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ReadTo
pLevelPropertyImplementation(IEdmTypeReference expectedPropertyTypeReference, DuplicatePropertyName
```

Here the message **A top-level property with name 'stat' was found in the payload; however, property and collection payloads must always have a top-level property with name value'** is confusing when I am not passing any collection just a key/value pair. My json representation for data is

```
{"stat":"Query"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json representation is a problem here change it to

{ "value": "Query" }